# Python User Input To List Separated Values

Tags: python, list

I've been trying to create a script that:

- Asks a user to input keywords
- Stores the user's input in a list
- Prints each value from the list

When I try to print the list all the values seem to be under the index `0`

```
inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()
inputwordslist = []

inputwordslist.append(inputwords)
inputwordslist = enumerate(inputwordslist)
print (list(inputwordslist))
```

Output Below:

```
What keywords are you looking for?This is a test
[(0, ['This', 'is', 'a', 'test'])]
```

Comment: `inputwords` is *already* a list because of your split, so just enumerate that

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, got it working now :)

`inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()  
inputwords.append(inputwords)

inputwords = enumerate(inputwords)

print (list(inputwords))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the easiest solution to your problem, @Chris_Rands already posted it in a comment to your question: `.split()` returns a list. You don't have to make a separate one for the result, just enumerate the value returned by the split function:

```
inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()
result = list(enumerate(inputwords))
print(result)
```

> What keywords are you looking for? This is a list of words.
>   [(0, 'This'), (1, 'is'), (2, 'a'), (3, 'list'), (4, 'of'), (5, 'words.')]

As noted in the other answer, it is a good idea to put a space after your prompt, that way there is separation between it and what the user is typing in:

```
inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for? ').split()
```

Your code will not work with python2 though, where the `input()` function is actually running the resulting string through `eval()`:

```
>>> input()
```

> 1 + 2 + 3
>        6

For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x).

If you want your code to be compatible with both python2 and python3, use this little snippet:

```
try:                       
    input = raw_input      
except NameError:          
    pass
```

This will make sure that `input` is pointing to the python3 version of the function.

Comment: Thanks very helpfull, I went with the suggest @Chris_Rands gave which is now working :) 

`inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()

inputwords.append(inputwords)
inputwords = enumerate(inputwords)
print (list(inputwords))`

Answer (score 0):

The result of `input(...).split()` *is* a list. Therefore all you need is:

```
inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()
print(list(enumerate(inputwords)))
```

Note that while this works in Python 3, in Python 2 you would have to use the `raw_input()` function instead - `input` expects a Python expression, and returns the result of evaluating that expression.

```
>>> inputwords = input('What keywords are you looking for?').split()
What keywords are you looking for?This, that and the other
>>> print(list(enumerate(inputwords)))
[(0, 'This,'), (1, 'that'), (2, 'and'), (3, 'the'), (4, 'other')]
```

It's helpful to put a space at the end of your prompt string, to clearly separate the prompt and the input.